# Could not resolve symbol

Tags: android

I am having the error :

> "Could not resolve symbol itemActivity."

This is in a method I want to use to open another activity. I have created the activity and i tried putting the name in the MainActivity. But its giving me error This is unusual as i have tried most of the solutions provide in previous question such as this. I have invalidate cache and restart. I have even rebuild the project but its still not working.

```
 package com.example.android.listofitems;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void openItemsList (View view) {
    Intent itemIntent = new Intent(this, itemActivity.class);
    startActivity(itemIntent);
}}
```

Comment: Could you show us your `manifest.xml` and `itemActivity.java`? Why your class named `itemActivity` instead of `ItemActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

This means that your class `itemActivity` doesn't exist.

> Java is a CASE sensitive language and therefore if you mistake a variable with cases, they will not be found

Check the real name of your activity or if it isn't there, Create an activity `itemActivity`. Though chances are your activity name is `ItemActivity` not `itemActivity`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. All I had to do was delete the intent statement then rebuild the main activity class.